# VB vlookup in different sheet for certain values

Tags: vba, if-statement, vlookup

can you please help me with a vlookup in a different sheet only for certain values?
I have tried for each, for i, different if's and so on.

I need the vba to bring in Sheet2 values from a Sheet1, but only for rows that have the value "De rediscutat" in a different column in Sheet2.

Below you have the code i wrote for this function:

````
Dim result As String
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Set Sheet2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set MyRange = Range("X2:X800")
If MyRange = "De rediscutat" Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("N2:N694").Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet2.Range("I2:I694"), Sheet1.Range("G2:M500"), 7, False)
End If
End Sub```

Thanks!
````

Comment: You can loop cell by cell to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a loop to do this. Your code also has much redundancy. This will hopefully get you started:

```
Dim cel As Range, myrange As Range

Set myrange = Sheet2.Range("X2:X800")

For Each cel In myrange
    If cel.Value = "De rediscutat" Then 
        'Grab whichever value you need and put it where you need it
    End if
next cel
```

I suggest using `Cel.Row` to get the row number of the current cell in the loop, or `Cel.Offset(,)` to get to a cell on the same row.

Comment: Easily done without looping.  Throw a filter on Column X, set  newRange to intersect(SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), N1:N & lastrow), newRange.Formula= .....

Answer (score 0):

`For Each` and `For i` will both work for looping through `MyRange` but you have not included either in your code.

The problem may not have been your loop, but rather the way you test the cell. `If MyRange = "De rediscutat"` will only work when MyRange` is a single cell.

If you `Dim cell As Range` recreate a `For Each cell In MyRange` loop and use `If cell = "De rediscutat" then it should work.